# Problem with Vue router duplicating App component

Tags: vue.js, routes, router, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

The router

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from '../App.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'App',
      component: App,
      meta: {
        title: 'App'
      }
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>

import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
  </div> 
  <div>
      <RouterView />
  </div>  
</template>
```

All other routes are working as well, but the route "/" displays duplicated content from App. If I do not include component: App in the routes file, the app works normal, but it gives me a warning that record with path "/" is missing a "component(s)".

Comment: You're basically causing recursion.  The router view is in App.vue and you're saying that route should render App.vue in the router view.  Create another component to render at the default route.  App.vue is the container that will render all of your views.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I was trying to make the App component work as Home component. Created a page Home.vue and change the route "/" to use component: Home, and it there were no more errors.